# If a partial derivative of a function equals 0, then can I set that variable equal to 0 in the function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Suppose I have $f(x, y)$ and I find that $ \partial f / \partial y = 0$. Can I then take f(x, y) = f(x, 0)? To be clear, I believe this substitution makes sense because if the partial derivative is 0, then the function must not depend on $y$, and so I could put anything in place of y.

I am trying to use this to show that:
$$
\partial / \partial y \int e^{-a(x+y)^2} dx = 0 => \int e^{-a(x+y)^2} dx = \int e^{-ax^2} dx
$$

EDIT: Some of the comments have pointed out that the above partial is indeed not equal to zero. I was short on time at the moment and wasn't able to write everything out. Here is what I was trying to prove:

$$
\partial / \partial \xi \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x + \frac{i}{2a}\xi)^2} = 0 \implies \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x + \frac{i}{2a}\xi)^2} = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x)^2}
$$

Comment: Mathjax tip: `\partial` produces the symbol $\partial$.

Comment: In reply to your paragraph, yes. The partial derivative being zero for arbitrary $x$ indicates that $f(x,y)$ only depends on $x$. You might as well write it as $f(x)$. But you can't use this to show the integral you wrote. $\partial_y e^{-y^2} = -2 y e^{-y^2} \neq 0$.

Comment: You may be interested to read this . . . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: Be a lot more precise. What does the integral sign actually mean here? And what exactly do you know about differentiating integrals?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses! I was not being entirely accurate here and have provided a clarification to the last part of my question for future readers of the question. My question has been answered now :)